# Не работает emmet в index.php

Tags: html, css, emmet

Помогите настроить emmet. Он работает в index.html, но не работает когда пишу код в index.php либо пишу код на JSX, использую Atom IDE

Comment: можно же поменять синтаксис - что бы Atom считал этот файл как html

Answer (score 2):

1. Зайти в:
   File - Setting - Keybindings - your keymap file
2. Нужно вписать в конец:
   'atom-text-editor[data-grammar="text html php"]:not([mini])':
   'tab': 'emmet:expand-abbreviation-with-tab'

Подробное решение:
  http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/393706/blog4385.html